# Catching "Failed to load resources" errors caused by HTML tags in a <webview>

Tags: javascript, html, webview, error-handling, google-chrome-app

I am loading web pages in Chrome App [webviews](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview).

I sometimes get "Failed to load resource" messages in the console for some of the `<script>` and `<img>` tags.  I want to catch these errors so I can act on them in JavaScript code, rather than have messages appear in the console.

I can not modify the HTML that I am loading, i.e., using AJAX to load the resources rather than HTML tags is not an option. "Fixing" the resources is also *not* what I am looking for - I just want some JavaScript code somewhere to know what is missing and take it from there.

Can I catch these errors in code, rather than having messages appear in the console?

Comment: BTW, addEventListener('consolemessage',... does not seem to catch what I am looking for.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a [<webview> WebRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-WebRequestEventInteface) API observer and see each resource load's status.
Does that not catch the resource load failures you're seeing?

```js
var webview = document.querySelector('webview');

webview.request.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
  if (details.statusLine.match(/^HTTP.*404/) {
    // some 404 happened...
    window.console.log('Failed url: ' + details.url);
  } else if ...
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>']});
```

The <webview> WebRequest API is similar to the [Chrome WebRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

Comment: Not exactly what I originally wanted to do (was looking for console's messages verbatim), but this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>These code might catch img load errors</h1>

<img id="img-1" src="url.jpg"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
 var img = document.getElementById('img-1');

 if (img.complete) {
    console.log('the img is already loaded.');
 }else{
    img.addEventListener('load', function(){
        console.log('img loaded.');
    });
 }

 img.addEventListener('error', function(){
    console.log('loading img failed.');  // you could try to load that resource again.
 });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**I've only tried `img` tag and it worked.**

Comment: Besides this being irrelevant for this question, please take a look at [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284563/reduce-try-this-answers-by-giving-a-helpful-message).

Comment: As specified in the question, I can not modify the HTML of the pages I am loading.

Comment: To clarify, I could programatically alter the the pages if that is possible, but I can't go in and add script tags or make other changes by hand.  The pages I am loading are not mine, there are potentially tens of thousands of them and millions of resource load attempts.

Comment: OK. I don't know how to do then if no script tags could be added. Sorry about that...