# how to get callback of Failed to load resource javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

**Hi** ,
sometimes server lost some assets (images , js ,css , files ) and it's appearing in console as

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

is there any way to have a callback for such errors , may it enables me to send server with report for lost asset .

**Thanks**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164462/catching-failed-to-load-resources-errors-caused-by-html-tags-in-a-webview

Answer (score 0):

## General

```
function URLStatusCheck(url,ifSuccess) {
    $.ajax(url, {
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true
    })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        ifSuccess.call(null,data)
    })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error");
    })
        .always(function () {
        //alert("complete");
    });
}
```

## For CSS :

```
function loadCss(cssText, callback){
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type='text/css';
    if(callBack != undefined){
        style.onload = function(){
            callBack();
        };
    }
    style.innerHTML = cssText;
    head.appendChild(style);
}
```

then

```
URLStatusCheck("http://path/to/file.css",function(cssContent){
   loadCss(cssContent,function(){
      console.log("New Css has been loaded")
    })
})
```

Then , do the same concept for others : `loadImg`, `loadJS`....